How do I solve a RACE CONDITION problem when using the WP REST API in a USSD system
I was recently testing a WP REST API integration I did for a USSD project which I paired with a Raffle Lottery WP site. So 2 tickets were to be purchased via the API for a particular game and those were the only 2 tickets left; however, while I was making the purchase another person was also making the same purchase and a RACE CONDITION occurred. Upon checking the entry ticket list, I had the ticket numbers but then the other person didn't receive any ticket numbers.
I designed the USSD system in such a way that the user is shown the available ticket quantity before a purchase is made, should the user select any number less than 1 or greater than the ticket quantity an error is raised.
But for a case where 2 people use the system at approximately the same time a RACE CONDITION occurs which I just discovered recently.
I am open to any potential solutions that will help me solve this issue.
USSD screenshot where a user is shown the number of tickets available for a selected game and is allowed to enter the number of tickets to be purchased
On the main site, upon receiving the API order request, I added some code to an action hook (this hook does the ticket assigning for API orders) to recheck the stock quantity before issuing the ticket numbers and return early if the stock is depleted.
            // Double-check the inventory to prevent race condition issues
            $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
            if ( $stock_quantity < $item->get_quantity() ) {
                error_log( sprintf( __( 'Not enough stock for &quot;%1$s&quot; (requested %2$d, available %3$d).', 'wc-lottery-pn' ), $product->get_name(), $item->get_quantity(), $stock_quantity ) );
                return;
            }

However, I'm not so sure if this solution entirely fixes the RACE CONDITION problem as 2 or more users can access the USSD system simultaneously.
